# Split SQL Column value and save count and results

Tags: sql, soql

I have a table with column c_name, c_services which got values like this:

```
 c_name  |      c_services 
---------------------------------------           
       A |   Email,Photos,Phone,Text 
       B |                Phone,Text  
       C |              Email,Photos  
       D |              Photos,Phone
```

From above table and column (c_services), I am trying to populate data in 5 more columns which are:-

```
1. Total_Services - based on number of services ex- 4 for c_name 'A'
2. Email - 1 if service present else 0
3. Photos - 1 if service present else 0
4. Phone - 1 if service present else 0
5. Text - 1 if service present else 0
```

For the new column 'Total_Services', I tried:

```
array_length(regexp_split_to_table(c_services, ','), 1)  Total_Services
or 
count(regexp_split_to_table(c_services)) Total_Service
or
count(string_split(c_services)) Total_Service
```

but it is not working. For other column, I am thinking of using a case when to populate 1 or 0 value. Please help.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or T-SQL? Please only use the appropriate tag.

Comment: Never, ever store data as comma separated items. It will only cause you lots of trouble.

Comment: Please tag your question properly.  MySQL and SQL Server are 2 completely different products.

Comment: Corrected the tag. The data source is from salesforce. I am writing an ETL query based job.

Comment: `SQL` is even worse tag to put.  SQL is just a common language used by multiple dbms vendors.  Each of them has their variation of syntax.

Comment: Related reading: [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3653462/10676716)

Comment: As a good example, the 2 solutions below are useless to you because you don't use MySQL.  You just wasted people's time.

Comment: Coorected the tag, its SOQL.

Comment: SOQL? I have never heard of it before.

Comment: SOQL -  Salesforce Object Query Language. Its very similar to SQL

Comment: @sudeep Never heard of that, but try below

Comment: @BilboBaggins Thanks for your input. Yes, I am working on it.

Answer (score 3):

Never heard of `SOQL` before but depending on how predictable and stable c_services column is, you could try this.

```
select t.*, (t.Email+t.Photos+t.Phone+t.Text) as total_service_count
from (select c_name
            ,case when c_services like '%Email%' then 1 else 0 end as Email
            ,case when c_services like '%Photos%' then 1 else 0 end as Photos
            ,case when c_services like '%Phone%' then 1 else 0 end as Phone
            ,case when c_services like '%Text%' then 1 else 0 end as Text
      from your_table) t;
```